# Combining a with statement and a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, with-statement, contextmanager

Consider the following python code which uses a context manager to acquire and release a resource:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def res(i):
    print(f'Opening resource {i}')
    yield
    print(f'Closing resource {i}')
```

Now assume that we need to use a couple of those resources

```
with res(0), res(1), res(2):
    print('Using resources.')
```

where the inner part depends on all the three resources being open simultaneously. After running the code above, we get the expected output:

```
Opening resource 0
Opening resource 1
Opening resource 2
Using resources.
Closing resource 2
Closing resource 1
Closing resource 0
```

If you have to use even more resources - `res(0) ... res(10)` is it possible to dynamically generate using a for loop the equivalent of the pseudo code below?

```
with res(0), res(1), ... , res(10):
    print('Using resources.')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what `contextlib.ExitStack` is for.

```
with ExitStack() as es:
    for x in range(10):
        es.enter_context(res(x))
```

Each context manager in the stack will be exited in the reverse order they were entered, once the `with` statement completes.